# Transfer javascript var to php var?

Tags: php, javascript, transfer

As i would like to determine whether theres a # in the link, and you only can do this in Javascript, I would like to transfer a JS variable to PHP.

So if i have:

```
if(location.hash){
var hash = location.hash;
```

the hash var needs to be turned in to a php $hash var..

I also tried if not possible, sending in post the variable,

```
$.post('photo.php?mode=grab', { hash: hash }, function(result) { 
// ..but then i got stuck, how should i transfer to php var from here?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$hashVar = $_POST['hash'];
```

This what you're after?

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
var hash = location.hash; 

 $.ajax
  ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: hash,
  //cache: false,
  success: function(html)
   {
    alert(html);
   }
  });

 return false;
});
```

Comment: no i already have this, i want a $hash(PHP variable) that contains the location.hash..

Comment: i'm confused. just change $hashVar to $hash? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Noo, ok you have the hash variable in javascript right? Now how would you get it out from javascript in to a php variable (lets call it $hash) forget the ajax call you made, i know you can get it to a variable through the ajax call, but then the variable is on file.php and not the current file you are in(e.g index.php)

Answer (score 0):

The posted string will be available to PHP in the `$_POST` variable.

Since you're posting a Javascript object using JQuery, PHP should receive it as a JSON string.

You can convert the JSON string into a PHP array using the PHP function [`json_decode()`](http://uk.php.net/json_decode).

Similarly, if you need to send an array back from PHP to Javascript, use `json_encode()` in PHP to reverse the process and create a JSON object.

Comment: Yes but the $.post will go to photo.php?mode=grab right? and in this file, the variable can get defined, but i want to get the php variable defined on the same page as the javascript variable is..

Comment: @Karem - if I'm understanding you correctly, then the answer is to post it using an old-style HTML form that forces a page reload.