# how to pass javascript variable to php function?

Tags: php

I need to pass javascript variable to php. This the code.this function call from dropdown.

```
 <script>
   function functionname2(){
       var ab = $("#ma").val(); 

      var va= <?php $ab1=ad;  echo TTable::model()->attr($ab1)?>; 
      if(va==='true')
          {
              var r=confirm("Press a button");
               if (r==true)
                {
                    x="You pressed OK!";
                }
                else
                {
                    x="You pressed Cancel!";
                } 
          }
  }   
   </script>
```

can any one know how to do this ?

Comment: AJAX will solve your problem

Comment: @HamZa it seems he totally misunderstood...seeing this line `<?php $ab1=ad;
                 echo TTable::model()->attr($ab1)?>; `

Comment: php executes before JS so you can't pass js variable to php in same page like this and what is ad in your php tag it seems to me that you are passing php var to js

Comment: hi nu123, see @Ankit comment... describe your case with some more information...so that others will understand your problem better and tend to help you....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer javascript var to php var?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713404/transfer-javascript-var-to-php-var)

Answer (score 4):

You can't : PHP generates the HTML code of your page, including javascript of course.

Do you pass an argument to God ? Obviously not.

But you can pray, and that's why [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) has been created later : using asynchronous calls, you can ask javascript to request a PHP service and to render the results without reloading the whole page.

If that's what you are looking for, then take a look at jQuery and its [AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) if you want to use it without too much pain.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because:

PHP  is run on server side (like your apache) while `Javascript` is run on client side (browser). `PHP` interpreter runs your statements such as `echo '<table>....</table>'` and finally such prints/outputs are all sent to the web browser hence it only contains whatever you print/ouput but no php script on client side. `Javascript`, `html` whatever on the server side, they are just `text` in php's point of view.

On client side you will only have whatever php generated but not php script so you can't pass like `javascript` to `php`. Now browser interprets that text as special text in it's point view depending upon their tags.

But however you can communicate with other `php` scripts on server by using javascript techniques such as ajax which dynamically sends the data to the `php script` on the server and takes the output back.

For example, you can dynamically send a search query to the php via database and take back the data from server and display it back on the browser through the technique ajax.

To further explain what you have to do, what approach you have to make. More information on what you want to achieve is needed.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a form with an element and submit that to your PHP page:

```
<form name="phpForm" action="" method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
    <input type="text" name="confirmation" value="" />
</form>
```

And set the value of the input before you submit it:

```
if (r==true)
{
    document.phpForm.confirmation.value = "You pressed OK!";
}
else
{
    document.phpForm.confirmation.value = "You pressed Cancel!";
}

document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```